# colab OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory, and mounting Google Drive. When I try to copy a zip file with size 65Gb it gets me the following error:

> [Errno 5] Input/output error

I used the below code to copy

```
%cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/###/data_odometry_gray.zip data_odometry_gray.zip
```

and also try this

```
import zipfile
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/drive/My Drive/###/data_odometry_gray.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall("/content/")
zip_ref.close()
```

but same error